# Web form (.aspx) naming convention

Tags: asp.net, webforms, naming-conventions

Should it be capitalised on the first letter? As an example, AddUser.aspx instead of adduser.aspx. Which is better?

Comment: You should ask separate questions for the second part of this question. It's much too broad as it now is.

Comment: @Shyju: Yes, I find that it just looks odd to the user when they see a URL with capitals like this: www.something.com/AddUser.aspx. Whereas www.something.com/adduser.aspx looks neater. Now I'm reminded that I can use URL Rewrite so I get the best of both worlds, www.something.com/adduser for the public eye and for my Visual Studio IDE I get to use AddUser.aspx.

Comment: @Weng Fai Wong, In my Web Application project I have an aspx file named default.aspx. When I compile it ,  I get the compiler error message , ASP class already has an default_aspx() function defined, for a temporary .cs file. How could I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think AddUser.aspx would be more commonly used than addUser.aspx or adduser.aspx.  An aspx is basically a .NET class, so it makes sense to name it using the standard class naming conventions (capitalize first letter, and first letter of every word).

Comment: Agree, AddUser.aspx should be better, since behind the aspx, it should have AddUser Class to inherit..

Answer (score 1):

I started making it all lowercase letters because I like to see the same case in the URL. Usually, most website URLs will be seen in lowercase only, so I don't want to add some uppercase chars to the URL.

It's personal preference, varies from person to person, project to project

Comment: +1 for personal preference, varying from developer to developer and from project to project.

Answer (score 0):

I always use capitals for the first letter. In fact for each word within the filename. This is because for me it makes the words within the name standout and therefore helps to more quickly give a clue as to the use of the file.